# iPhone image swap screen not updating

Tags: iphone, timer

I know there is most probably something seriously wrong here because I only started on iOS yesterday but I can't seem to get this to update the screen properly, the count works fine and it's incrementing and checking the conditions correctly just that the screen doesn't get displayed, can anybody point me in the right direction please?

```
@implementation draw2D


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code
        [self myTimer];
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code
    [self updateBackground];
}

NSTimer *timer = nil;
int count = 0;

- (void)myTimer
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateBackground) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    if (count < 1) {
        count++;
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }


}

- (void)updateBackground:
{
    if(count == 1)
    {
        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        [myImage drawInRect:imageRect];
        [myImage release];
    //  count++;
    } 
    else 
        if (count == 0) 
        {
            UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SCENE_002.png"];
            CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
            [myImage drawInRect:imageRect];
            [myImage release];
    //      count = 0;
        }
    [self myTimer];
}
@end
```

EDIT: It displays the first image, but never swaps to the second.

Answer (score 1):

On second look, you have two things methods calling updateBackground, one is drawRect, which can be called any time you're updating the display, and on the timer fire.  In the myTimer method, you're changing the count value, with the expectation the screen will refresh 0.5 seconds later.

I'm suspicious that the reason one image is never displayed is that it may be being drawn, but the call to drawInRect might fire drawRect, which could then blit the *other* image on top of the recently drawn image.

So, basically I'd remove the call to updateBackground from drawRect:

** ORIGINAL ANSWER:

[UIView drawRect] is only called when necessary.  After the initial call, UIKit just caches the result internally and continues to redraw the cached copy to the display.

What you need to do is send a signal to the view that it needs to be refresh.  You can do that by adding the line:

```
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

In your updateBackground selector.

Also, why are you re-creating the timer after each time it fires, instead of changing the repeats parameter to YES?

Comment: My intention was to have the timer created and started as the view begins. I tried placing it in the initWithFrame method but it would not work. So I shifted to this which I see now is wrong. Am I right in understanding that drawRect is called on every screen refresh? If so, how do I start my timer independently? Thanks

Comment: As far as initWithFrame: not being run - Is the UIView sub-class being loaded from a NIB or XIB file?  If so, initWithFrame: isn't called, initWithCoder: is.  A nasty little thing Apple never really makes clear.